# Why is $E[l]\cong\mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z$ for an elliptic curve $E$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

[René Schoof's 1995 paper](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~schoof/ctg.pdf) contains the following statement about an elliptic curve $E$ (at the bottom of page 233):

> [...], we use the subgroup $E[l]$ of $l$-torsion points of $E(\overline{\mathbb F_p})$:
>   $$E[l] = \{\,P\in E(\overline{\mathbb F_p}) \,:\, l\cdot P=0 \,\} \text.$$
>   The group $E[l]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z$.

Why is this the case? This seems somewhat arbitrary to me, why not $\mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z$ or any other group whose exponent is $l$? How would you go about proving this (just hints are welcome as well)?

Comment: Do you know why it is true for an elliptic curve over the complex numbers?

Comment: Multiplication by $\ell$ is a separable isogeny of degree $\ell^2$, and the only finite group of order $\ell^2$ with exponent $\ell$ is $(\mathbf{Z}/\ell \mathbf{Z})^2$. All of this can be found in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* book.